# Laravel with nginx returns a internal server error

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

On my localhost server, using `php artisan serve` the server runs perfectly, but when i uploaded to my vps that's not work

```
2020/08/14 01:54:45 [error] 9333#0: *5 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ComposerAutoloaderInit643cdf30505619f27cedca17fc9059c6::getLoader() in /home/sites/storm/api.stormc.net/vendor/autoload.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sites/storm/api.stormc.net/public/index.php(24): require()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/sites/storm/api.stormc.net/vendor/autoload.php on line 7" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.69.3.155, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: "api.stormc.net"
```

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
      
    root /home/sites/storm/api.stormc.net/public;

    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to run `composer global dump-autoload` 

is this configuration about your laravel application in sites-available dir?

Comment: I tried that, but does't work and what you refer to "laravel application configuration in sites-available dir"?

Comment: I will write an answer, check it and let me know it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

set up your Nginx, by following these steps:

1. we need to give the webserver user write access to the storage and cache folders, where Laravel stores application-generated files:

   ```
   $ sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /home/sites/storm/api.stormc.net/storage
   $ sudo chown -R www-data.www-data /home/sites/storm/api.stormc.net/bootstrap/cache
   ```
2. we need to configure Nginx to serve the content. To do this, we’ll create a new virtual host configuration file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available`:

   ```
   $sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/name-of-project
   ```

The following configuration file contains the recommended settings for Laravel applications on Nginx:

```
*/etc/nginx/sites-available/name-of-project*    
   server {
        listen 80;
        server_name server_domain_or_IP;
        root /home/sites/storm/api.stormc.net/public;
    
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    
        charset utf-8;
    
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
    
        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    
        error_page 404 /index.php;
    
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;//check with your installed version on server 
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    
        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
            deny all;
        }
    }
```

3. To activate the new virtual host configuration file, create a symbolic link to name-of-project in `sites-enabled`:

   ```
   $sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/name-of-project /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
   ```
4. To confirm that the configuration doesn’t contain any syntax errors, you can use:

   ```
   $sudo nginx -t
   ```

You should see output like this:

```
$ nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
$ nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

5. To apply the changes, reload Nginx with:

   ```
   $sudo systemctl reload nginx
   ```